# How to SPSiteDataQuery from one SharePoint farm to another farm?

Tags: 2007

I want to use SPSiteDataQuery to query from one SP farm to another. Both farms exist on the same active directory. What would be the most suitable approach? A custom web service might do it? An ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a web service, and querying the web service from the other farm. I don't think you'll be able to use the SPSiteDataQuery object itself across the farm boundary.

Comment: That's correct. Because it's a different farm you have to use Web Services (either out of the box or custom) to query the data.

Comment: I followed this at first:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040(v=office.12).aspx

This looks a pretty good intro:
http://malikhan.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/creating-custom-webservice-in-sharepoint-2007/ 

And this seems pretty thorough too:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/creating-a-custom-web-service-for-sharepoint-13553

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query across farms, the best way I think is Search. If you efficiently use keyword and full text queries, you can fine tune your search results similar to SPSiteDataQuery (or even better) across many farms without compromising on performance

Taking the step forward, If you have the powerful FAST search you can find almost anything!